# How can I see what interfaces belong to the default routing instance on the SRX?

Tags: routing, nat, juniper, srx

I'm working with routing instances on the Juniper SRX. When you configure NAT you have the option to specify "to" and "from" statements, with these option you can specify NAT to translate to or from a routing instance. On the Routing Instance list you get, you can configure the "default" routing instance. I'm assuming that every interface that wasn't assigned a specific routing instance belongs to the default but I want to be sure, is there a way to verify?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can check

1. `show interfaces routing-instance all terse` which will list all interfaces and their routing instance (See example)
2. `show confiuration routing-instances` which is going to show the configuration of any routing instances you have, you will need to check out the interface stanza
3. Check the routing table and see if the routes from your interface are being shown in another routing instance.

**Example**

The below shows the interfaces are all in the default instance except fe-0/0/6.0 which is in a routing instance called `test`

```
root@Gareth-FW> show interfaces fe-0/0* routing-instance all terse
Interface        Admin Link Proto  Local                Instance
fe-0/0/0.0       up    up   inet   1.1.1.1/30
                                   172.30.1.100/24      default
fe-0/0/1.0       up    up   inet   192.168.218.240/24   default
fe-0/0/6.0       up    up   inet   10.10.10.2/24
                                   10.77.77.2/30        test
fe-0/0/7.0       up    up   inet   10.10.10.1/24        default
```